# Is there any standard method for finding the function defined by a Taylor/Laurent series?

Tags: taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Say you have a Taylor series defined by

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$

Is there any standard way to figure out what function is defined by the series? One option I see is just looking at the coefficients and finding some function that satisfies the values for $f(c)$, $f'(c)$, etc, where $c$ is the point the Taylor series is centered on, but it seems as though it would be hard to define a function with just some values in mind. You could say the same for a Laurent series, although I can imagine that would be much harder given that you would have to figure out all the nasty coefficients.

Comment: As written, this is not a Taylor series. You need to have the form $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$ for a Taylor series. This could be anything in your case.

Comment: You know, most functions are not like $\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$, and so on (which are elementary functions). There is a taylor series that have not closed form.

Comment: There are only so many functions, Taylor (or Laurent) series of which is tabulated, so you can look up coefficients. All other representations either yet to be discovered, or don't event have a closed form in terms of elementary or special functions.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is through differential equations. Assuming your power series $f$ has radius of convergence $R>0$, you can differentiate it (at libidum) on $(-R,R)$, and doing so and rearranging the coefficients you may end up with a differential equation on $f$. If you can solve it to get an analytic form for the solutions, you will get an analytic form for $f$.

As a simple example, look at the power series defined by $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$, with radius of convergence $R=1$. Differentiating on $(-1,1)$, you get
$$\begin{align}
f^\prime(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n-1}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) x^{n} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}
= x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} \\
&= x f^\prime(x) + f(x)
\end{align}$$
i.e. 
$$
f^\prime(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1-x}, \qquad x\in (-1,1)
$$

Solving this differential equation, you get $f(x) = \frac{f(0)}{1-x}$, and since $f(0) = 1$, you obtain $f$.

(of course, this particular example is not interesting, as the original series is easy to compute by other means; but it illustrates the technique)